# window scrolls top after wrapper gets overflow:hidden via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, overflow, hidden, scrolltop

I don't want the window scroll to top after my wrapper gets overflow:hidden via jQuery.

```
$('#shownav').click(function(event) {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('noscroll');      
    return false;
});
```

html:

```
<div id="shownav"> navigation </div>
<div id="wrapper"> long content </div>
```

css:

```
.noscroll {overflow:hidden;}
```

the navigation is `position:fixed;`

the wrapper has `position: relative;` and `width: 100%; height:100%;`

If I scroll down the long long content and once click the #shownav the content scrolls to the top like scrollTop(0). But I don't what this! What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#shownav').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('noscroll');
});
```

Comment: works well for desktop browsers. but all mobile browsers I could test don't make it! :/ they don't make the body overflow:hidden.